# Scroll certain views in coordinator layout with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Hello I have `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBar`, `Toolbar` and `RecyclerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_photos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to leave `Toolbar` on top and don't want to move it, but let `LinearLayout` scroll below it (under the `Toolbar`).

Also I found that RecyclerView's not working with Coordinator layout. It doesn't trigger AppBar scroll events. If I will wrap it inside NestedSCrollView it will work but RecyclerView's not recycling view holders then so it's doesn't work for me.

Could anyone help to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't implement it in the described way. RecyclerView doesn't send scroll events to AppaBar layout (what is really strange) so I need to split every view on that screen and make recycler view adapter handle them all in one recycler view. Thanks all for answers and time spent on this!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
   ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_photos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi! This way RecyclerView won't recycler view holders, so it doesn't work for me. I already tried it. Anyway thanks for answer and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your toolbar and linear layout in a [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html). Then use appropriate collapse mode attributes. For example, you could use `pin` for your toolbar and `parallax` for your linear layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        ...
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        <LinearLayout
            ...
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

You need the dependency for design support library in your app's `build.gradle`:

`implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_library_version"`

[More on coordinator and collapsing toolbar layouts](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: Hello! I already tried this. I need my linear layout to be placed below toolbar, in ur example it will overlap toolbar. Also recycler view is not triggering appbar scroll events.

Comment: @OlexiiMuraviov In that case, you might want to consider one of these  options:
1. Use action bar instead of title bar, and put linear layout only in collapsing toolbar (use a theme with action bar for this activity).
2. Make linear layout the first item of recycler view
3. Define custom behaviour for the toolbar and linear layout (not sure about this one)